# How to Import Local Git Repository to Project in XCode

Tags: git, xcode

So, recently, I am working on a local git repository. Also recently, I decided to switch to XCode. However, on the welcome page, there is no option to import a local git repository, only an option to clone a repository on the web. How do I do this?

Comment: Hmm… I don’t use Xcode anymore, but can you load the file via `file://Path/To/Your/Repo`? Because Git itself is flexible enough to interact with “remote” repos that are just file system paths.

Comment: @JakeGould Got this error: failed to resolve path 'file://Users/Aaron/git/cuddly-system/.git': No such file or directory (-1)
However, that file exists.

Comment: Okay, how about trying this; note the three backslashes after `file:`: `file:///Users/Aaron/git/cuddly-system/.git`